# Definition of law of composition: with or without closure

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a proper understanding of this concept in Artin's algebra text.

We're given a set with "law of composition" given by $a*b = ba$, and are asked to prove that the set is a group. My first inclination is to check closure. My question is: do I even need to check closure? A binary operation seems to come with closure attached to it. Does a law of composition necessitate it, or does it just tell me how to combine two elements?

It seems to me that, in order to be well-defined, a law of composition has to be closed, in which case checking closure is not necessary.

Edited for clarity: This is the problem from Artin I am looking at.

> Let $G$ be a group. Define an opposite group $G^{\circ}$ with law of composition $a*b$ as follows: The underlying set is the same as $G$, but the law of composition is $a*b = ba$. Prove that $G^{\circ}$ is a group.

Comment: What is a set with "law of composition"?  Some context is missing, making this impossible to answer.

Comment: For example, I could feasibly call the natural numbers with multiplication as the law of composition an instance of your scenario.  This is clearly not a group, though, so something is missing from your question.

Comment: I've edited the question with the statement of the problem from Artin I am looking at.

Comment: I would rephrase your question.  You are given a GROUP and then asked to prove that this new thing is a group.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But the 'law of composition' is different from that of $G$. Is it fair to say that it is by definition closed?

Comment: Yes, closure is not the hard part of the exercise.

Comment: Understood, thank you. If I could ask one more question: is it a fair interpretation that when Artin writes $ba$, he is referring to the law of composition in $G$?

Comment: Yes, of course.  The operation $*$ is just the mirror image of the operation in $G$.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.